# Problems with importing data into code

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm trying to make a code that will import data from a text file and graph it with matplotlib here what i have so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = []
y = []

readFile = open ('C:/Users/Owner/Documents/forcecurve.txt', 'r')

sepFile = readFile.read().split('\n')

readFile.close()

for plotPair in sepFile:
    xAndY = plotPair.split('\t')
    x.append(int (xAndY[0]))
    y.append(int (xAndY[1]))
print x
print y

plt.plot (x, y)



plt.xlabel('Distance (Nanometers)')
plt.ylabel('Force (Piconewtons)')

plt.show()
```

Once running this I get the error

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,40.9'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file appears to be comma-delimited (`1,40.9`), not tab delimited, so you need to split by commas rather than tabs. Change

```
    xAndY = plotPair.split('\t')
```

to

```
    xAndY = plotPair.split(',')
```

Alternatively, it might be easier to use the `csv` module to read in the file. As a simple example:

```
import csv

readFile = open ('C:/Users/Owner/Documents/forcecurve.txt', 'r')

x = []
y = []

r = csv.reader(readFile)
for x1, y1 in r:
    x.append(int(x1))
    y.append(int(y1))

readFile.close()
```

Comment: In Python 3.x, always use the `newline=''` option with `open` ([docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html#csv.reader)) when used for `csv`. In Python 2.X, use 'rb' ([docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader)).